# Are certain functions in 2-D not functions in 3-D?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When in 2-D, we say that the relationship y = x$^2$ is a function because for every input 'x' there is one and only one output 'y'. My understanding is that the definition of a function in 3-D is that for every input (x,y) there is an output z. However, if I graph y = x$^2$ in 3-D I'll have a graph where every ordered pair (x,y) yields an infinite number of z-values, since there is no restriction on what 'z' can be. Does that mean that y = x$^2$ and functions like it are not actually functions in 3-D, or am I misunderstanding the definition of a function in 3 dimensions?

Comment: That's a slightly strange question, since clearly the formula $y=x^2$ doesn't define $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. (But it still defines $y$ as a function of $x$ and $z$ in three dimensions, for what that's worth.)

Comment: @HansLundmark that actually clarified the confusion for me very well, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the strictest sense, a function is a set of pairs of inputs and outputs such that each input is unique. The formula $y = x^2$ isn't really a function, but it defines $y$ as a function of $x$. We could write $y : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, y(x) = x^2$, meaning "$y$ is a function with real number inputs and outputs such that when its input is $x$, its output is $x^2$".

So in 3D space, the formula $y = x^2$ defines a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that you could look at in a few ways. For example:

- For every distinct $x$ and $z$, there is a unique value of $y$, so it defines $y$ as a function of $x$ and $z$ - i.e. $y : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, y(x, z) = x^2$.
- For every distinct $x$, there is a unique value of $y$, but an unrestricted number of possible values of $z$, so it defines a relation between values of $x$ and values of the pair $(y, z)$, e.g. $(y, z) \sim x$ if $x = y^2$.
- If $z$ is real and $y$ is a non-negative value, then it defines a pair of functions  $x_1, x_2 : \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x_1(y, z) = \sqrt{y}$ and $x_2(y, z) = -\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, my confusion was that because of how Calculus III has been presented to me this whole time I had it made up in my mind that (x,y) is the input and z is the output. I didn't consider that this would simply be a function of input (x,z) and output y.